# Is there a lens operator to combine %~ and fmap

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I have the following code

```
u & currentDay %~ fmap (addDays 1)
```

`currentDay` returns a `Maybe` which is why I need the `fmap`.
Is there already an operator to combine `%~` and `fmap` (like `%~<$>` ;-)) or a clever way to do so ?

Comment: How about `u & currentDay %~ (addDays 1 <$>)`?

Comment: Indeed, but I'm more interesting in knowing if there is already an operator to do so in the lens library. There are so many and some are hard to grasp.

Comment: You can use [mapped](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.11/docs/Control-Lens-Setter.html#v:mapped): `u & currentDay . mapped %~ addDays 1`

Comment: @cchalmers Interesting. But there is no (already existing) operator combining `mapped` and `%~`.?

Comment: @mb14 Not in lens (the setting combinators are [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.11/docs/Control-Lens-Setter.html#g:4)). But it wouldn't be too hard to write your own.

Comment: @cchalmers Ok. I don't like to reinvent the wheel so I was just checking it wasn't existing already. `mapped` is probably what I was looking for in fact. Could you write it as an answer  so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no existing operator for this but you could easily define your own:

```
%$~ :: Functor f => ASetter s t (f a) (f b) -> (a -> b) -> s -> t
l %$~ f = over a (fmap f)
```

The standard way to do this is to use the [`mapped`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.11/docs/Control-Lens-Setter.html#v:mapped) setter:

```
u & currentDay . mapped %~ addDays 1
```

Since your mapping over a `Maybe` you could also use [`_Just`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.11/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html#v:_Just) prism:

```
u & currentDay . _Just %~ addDays 1
```